# Are there any ways of expressing sarcastic thanks in French?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

In English, for instance, one might say "Thanks for nothing". Is there anything like this in French - would it even be the same?

Just a side note: I have heard a term which I cannot spell and have not seen written; it sounds something like "jour merci", but of course that would make no sense. I considered 'dieu merci', but in the context it did not make much sense either.

In [this prank video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzYNdDopgtU&feature=youtu.be&t=7m20s), for instance, at around 7:19 I hear this phrase and although the captions are heplful for the translation I would like the French words to go along with it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For jour merci, it's a very shortened version of: Je vous remercie...which can be written as: j'vous remercie. where the RE is "escamoté" or blurred over. Spoken French, like spoken English, has a lot of shortening, y'know?

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. Is that kind of shortened language more prominent in parts of France than others?

Comment: Haven't heard that "jour merci".

Comment: He says what sounded like "jour merci pas Camille" to me before Lambie and the others clarified

Comment: No, Alex, this contracting or shortening is all over France and in all varieties of French. Just like in English. [He said, j'ne vous remercie pas]. I listened to video after I commented, fyi.

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre assistance!

Comment: Maybe "jvour merci pas" - that would make more sense than "jour merci pas".

Comment: For the part of your question that doesn't concern what's being said on the video, "Merci pour rien" is the literal translation of "Thanks for nothing" and would have the same meaning as the English version. Also, in the right context, "Merci quand même" said in a sarcastic tone and/or with the appropriate body language (grimace, shoulder shrug, flipping the bird) could mean "Thanks anyway, but you've been of little or no help."

Comment: @Lambie J'ai vu dans le livre «Exercices d'oral en contexte» qu'il est une règle d'oral: on affaiblit souvent la prononciation de "e" s'il y a deux "e"s (pas forcément pour le mot «je»), et la prononciation de «vous», comme j[e] n[e] v[ous].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the video, he says "*Je vous remercie pas, Camille*".

*Remercier* means "to thank", "*je vous remercie*" is an alternative way to say "*merci*", it's more polite, a little more formal. It could be translated by "you have my thanks".

So literally, "*je (ne) vous remercie pas*" would be "you do not have my thanks". It's not that common, saying it is a way of telling people you don't like their behavior while still being polite.

Answer (score 2):

In [this dictionary of expressions](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=je+ne+vous+remercie+pas), you can compare between french and English the meanings and sens of:

> je ne vous remercie **pas**.

If one wants to "focus on sarcasticity", old french may be used:

> je ne vous remercie **point**.

Google translation gives the same result for both expressions:

> I do not thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can say a standard word with some sarcastic addition, like "je vous remercie, vous êtes bien brave".

Answer (score 1):

So as Teleporting Goat wrote, "je ne vous remercie pas" in the video is a way of not saying thank you by saying something. "Je ne vous dis pas merci" is another possibility.

---

Note that it can be used friendly to... indeed... say *thank you*... yes, I know...

Like if someone helps you and you say "je ne te dis pas merci" because saying *thank you* would mean nothing compared to what he did for you. Or because you are so good friends that you don't need to say *thank you* (but you need to say that you don't need to say *thank you*, to thank them, still).

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know that.I can see the logic behind, bt I don't think I've heard it before.

Comment: Really? I often say "bon ben j'te dis pas merci !" to thank someone.

Comment: Yeah I get the idea, I just don't know anyone who uses it :)

Comment: "j'te dis pas merci !" would not be so sarcastic, right? I would use it sometimes in a straight fashion, not sarcastically.

Comment: For me, it is either sarcatic or straight out aggressive.

Comment: Do you mean "sarcastic" in the meaning of "ironic" (to say the opposite of what you want to be understood)? Whatever, what I meant is you can say "j'te dis pas merci !" to indeed say thank you. "Bon ben, tu m'as sauvé la vie sur ce coup, j'te dis pas merci" means you want to say thank you but it won't be enough so you don't even say it (and you say you don't say it so it's like you say it). Of course it can be used to say you really don't say thank you, like in "c'est pas sympa ce que t'as fait là, franchement j'te dis pas merci".

Comment: I think it depends very much on the context, and the tone used to say it.

Comment: Yes, of course!

Answer (score 1):

Dans la langue parlée il existe une façon à la fois très simple et très compliquée qui présuppose une grande versatilité du locuteur avec la prononciation. Cela consiste  à prononcer seulement le mot « merci », mais d'une manière très anormale, en exagérant le volume de la première syllabe et en lui imprimant une intonation très spéciale qu'il faut avoir apprise par l'écoute répétée de personnes à l'aise avec la langue parlée. Un des moyens les plus simples de coder cela dans la langue écrite est « MEERR…ci ».